# numpy performance on multiple cpus

Tags: python, numpy, hpc, openblas

I am curious about numpy's performance on hpc machine with up to 128 cpus per node. I am running a dot product of two matrices, both have NxN elements, and progressively increasing the ncpus I request for this operation. Below is a graph showing the performance for different numbers of N versus the ncpus (labels stand for size of array N^2).

Does anyone know why the performance plateaus after ~20 cpus?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.show_config()
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blis_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
```

[image]

Comment: There are several env vars you might be able to tweak to scale further. Do you know what `OMP_NUM_THREADS` is set to, for example?

Comment: I set this equal to the ncpus I request.